# pass objects from one activity to another to CHANGE THEIR VALUES

Tags: java, android, object

If I have 3 class: `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `A`.

Please see my pseudo code below.
I would like to know how to pass objects from one activity to another.
Every explanation I've found so far referred to pass objects in order to **PRINT** them in the second activity. However, I need to **CHANGE THEIR VALUES BY USING THEIR METHODS**. Class A cannot be a static class.
Please advice what is the best way to do so.

```
class MainActivity {
  A a1 = new A();
  A a2 = new A();
}

class A {
  double a;
  setA(...){...};
  getA(...){...};
}

class SecondActivity {
  EditText b1; //data is saved in Shared Preference
  double c1 = Double.parseDouble(b1); //convert from string to double in short
  a1.setA(c1); //how to access instance a1?
}
```

Comment: In this example you should be editing the SharedPreferences, not an instance of a local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a singleton to hold some number of instances of `A`. If you have data that you want to persist in an app session consistently across different Activities, you cannot reliably store that in an Activity (Activities can be killed and recreated in the background).

For example, here's a way to hold an arbitrary number of unique instances in a map:

```
static class AHolder {
    private static AHolder instance;

    static AHolder getInstance() {
        if( instance == null ) {
            instance = new AHolder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private AHolder() {}

    private HashMap<String,A> myCollection = new HashMap<>();

    void addA(String key, A val) {
        myCollection.put(key,val);
    }

    boolean hasA(String key) {
        return myCollection.containsKey(key);
    }

    A getA(String key) {
        return myCollection.get(key);
    }
}
```

Then in `MainActivity` you can add instances of `A` to this with

```
AHolder ah = AHolder.getInstance();
if(!ah.hasA("A1") ) {
    ah.addA("A1",new A());
}
if(!ah.hasA("A2") ) {
    ah.addA("A2",new A());
}
A a1 = ah.getA("A1");
A a2 = ah.getA("A2");
```

and to access and edit them in the other activity you can do

```
AHolder ah = AHolder.getInstance();
A a1 = ah.getA("A1");
A a2 = ah.getA("A2");
```

Comment: Thanks! If I create  a singleton as you suggested, does it make saving data in SharedPreference unnecessary? Would the values in myCollection will be saved everytime I exit and reopen the app?

Comment: No, the singleton will only persist as long as the app is running. If you want it saved from session to session you still need a SharedPreferences or database. You could have the singleton manage that though (so have it load the saved items in its constructor, and have a `saveItem` method you can call). I can update the answer to show an example if you want.

Comment: Thanks, I got it :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is one option. You can use serializable and parcelable interfaces and pass data through intent from one activity to anoter.

Comment: If you do this to pass a Serializable object from one intent to another, it makes a copy of the object, so you're not operating on the original instance any more. Modifications you made in the second activity would not be present in the first activity if you pressed back. That may or may not matter depending on how it's used.